# Variable amount on express checkout digital goods

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

It is possible to let customers change the amount of money they have to pay?

Let say if the product has amount of 200, it is possible for custmer to pay just 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but my immediate response would be no, that's not possible unless you allow them to do so.

The payment will be processed for whatever amount you pass into the API request.  If your shopping cart is setup showing an item is $200 but somehow you let the customer adjust that so the price sent in your API request is only $10, then yeah it would only charge $10.

Just make sure fields that have to do with pricing aren't editable and that won't be an issue...unless that's what you're wanting..??

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to know if the product price is 200 can the buy pay 10 then 190 ?

Comment: Sure.  There are numerous ways you could go about doing that, though.  Do you want the buyer to have to login again and approve the additional $90 later, or do you want to be able to automatically bill them that amount when you need to?

Comment: second option suits best, it is possible?

Comment: Yes, there a couple of ways to accomplish that but since you're already working with Express Checkout we'll stick to that.  Basically, in your SetExpressCheckout request you'll include the billing agreement parameters.  This way when the person completes the first payment they will also be agreeing to allow you to process future payments on their behalf.  When they agree to that and complete the payment you'll get a transaction ID back just like normal.  You can take that transaction ID and pass it into a DoReferenceTransaction API request to process future payments as necessary.

Comment: This is something you'll need to get approved for, though, so you'll need to submit a request to PayPal to use Express Checkout Billing Agreements w/ Reference Transactions and have them enable that for you.